# phonegap jquery mobile pagecontainer change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I started with Phonegap and I try to combine it with jquery mobile. 
I have this piece of code and I cannot find anything wrong. But it does not change the page.
HTML code:

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <title>Clever Games Collection</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="page1">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                <h1>Clever Games Collection</h1>

            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="guess">test</a></td>
                        <td><a href="activities">test</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="story">test</a></td>
                        <td><a href="quiz">test</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <h1>Footer</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="page2">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                <h1>Header - Page 1</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content"></div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <h1>Footer</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery-mobile.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pageController.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
```

Javascript code

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },

    onDeviceReady: function() {
        pagesController.onReady();
    }
};

var pagesController = {
    onReady: function() {
        $("a").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', '#page2', {
                transition: 'flip',
                changeHash: false,
                reverse: true,
                showLoadMsg: true
            });
        });

    }
};
```

When I click on the link it does not switch the pages. I found many answers here and tried them but none of them works.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Make sure `click` listener is attached to anchors. Another note, in anchors, add hash `#` in `href`, e.g. `href=#foo`.

Comment: I am sure that click is attached because I have alerts inside. Before and after pagecontainer function and both were functioning. I also used the # in href but it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add link to jquery style sheets.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.css" />
```